# The target-entity XXXXXXX cannot be found in XXXXXXX

Tags: php, docker, symfony, doctrine, symfony6

My issue is the following:

> The target-entity App\Entity\LicenseType cannot be found in 'App\Entity\License#LicenseType'.

[Screenshot of full Symfony error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7a1h.png)

I tried several things here is the current state of my code

This is my License entity :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Entity\LicenseType;

/**
 * License
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="License", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="license_token_unique", columns={"token"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="license_owner_user_foreign", columns={"owner_user"}), @ORM\Index(name="license_license_type_foreign", columns={"license_type"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\LicenseRepository")
 * 
 */
class License
{
```

This is my LicenseType property :

```php
 /**
     * @var LicenseType
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="LicenseType", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="license_type", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $LicenseType;
```

Comment: Your LicenseType class has the `@ORM\Entity` annotation?  You also tried clearing any caches?

Comment: @Cerad yes the LicenseType class have the @ORM\Entity ,  I have cache clear and check if db is update.

Comment: Just for fun, comment out the `use App\Entity\LicenseType;` in the License.php file.  Entities (and classes in general) that are in the same directory don't need use statements.  Also see what `bin/console doctrine:mapping:info` says about LicenseType.

Comment: @Cerad ```Found 17 mapped entities:

 [OK]   App\Entity\Contact
 [OK]   App\Entity\Receipt
 [OK]   App\Entity\Collection
 [OK]   App\Entity\CustomerCard
 [OK]   App\Entity\Ticket
 [OK]   App\Entity\User
 [OK]   App\Entity\Document
 [OK]   App\Entity\ResetPasswordRequest
 [OK]   App\Entity\Usergroup
 [OK]   App\Entity\License
 [OK]   App\Entity\LicenseType
 [OK]   App\Entity\Adress
 [OK]   App\Entity\Accounting
 [OK]   App\Entity\Feature
 [OK]   App\Entity\Recu
 [OK]   App\Entity\Calendar
 [OK]   Vich\UploaderBundle\Entity\File ```this is the return of the command.

Comment: And you tried commenting out the user statement?  Nothing else funky going on like custom entity mapping plugins?  Your other relations are working as expected?  I have also seen some cases where case sensitivity was involved.

Comment: Please post the `App\Entity\LicenseType` entity source-code. Usually this is caused by a missing `namespace App\Entity;` or `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;` could also be a typo in the file name `LicenseType.php` Also concur that `use App\Entity\LicenseType;` should not be needed.

Comment: The problem is solved it came from the name of the file of my entity LicenseType which was Licentype instead of LicenseType . I thank you for trying to help me.